# Countour integral using residue theorem: $ \int_{\gamma} \tanh(z) dz $ where $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ and $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, contour-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Evaluate the integral $$ \int_{\gamma} \tanh(z) dz $$
where $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ and $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

I want to do this using the residue theorem but I am unsure of how to work out the poles of $\tanh(z)$. I've tried to use the Taylor expansion and writing it in terms of $\cosh(z)$ and $ \sinh(z) $ but I'm getting confused.

Comment: $\tanh z = \sinh z/\cosh z$, so the poles of $\tanh z$ are the zeros of $\cosh z$. Can you solve $e^{z} + e^{-z} = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

We know that the zeroes of $\cosh z$ appear in $Z=i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\mathbb{Z}\right)$, since $\cosh z = \cos(iz)$, and they are all simple zeroes. Over $Z$, $\sinh z$ is a regular non-vanishing function (by the relation $\cosh^2 z-\sinh^2 z=1$, if you like). Since $\frac{\pi}{2}>1$, $\tanh z$ has no singularities in the unit disk, so its contour integral over $\gamma$ is just zero by the residue theorem.